# Is this a lattice?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, topological-groups, haar-measure, arithmetic-groups

Let $R$ be a locally compact ring (commutative with unit) and let $D\subset R$ be a discrete cocompact subring (cocompact means the additive group $R/D$ is compact). Let $G$ be a semisimple linear algebraic group defined over $D$. Is it true that $G(D)$ is a lattice in $G(R)$, i.e. is
$$
\mathrm{vol}\big(G(D)\backslash G(R)\big)<\infty
$$
for any Haar measure on $G(R)$?
If not true in this generality, how if the topology on $R$ is defined by an absolute value?

Comment: When $R$ is Lie connected I guess this follows from Borel–Harish-Chandra. At least the case $R=\mathbf{R}^k\times\mathbf{C}^\ell$ is covered. But the general case seems to follow. I think in this case $R$ is a finite-dimensional $\mathbf{R}$-algebra, which can be supposed to be local by a product argument, and then it seems easy, say by induction on $k$ such that $M^k=0$ where $M$ is the maximal ideal.

Comment: Borel–Harish-Chandra covers many other cases, such as $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]\subset\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{Q}_p$, probably even $\mathbf{Q}\subset$ (adeles) and generalizations; finite characteristic analogues such as $\mathbf{F}_q[t]\subset\mathbf{F}_q(\!(t^{-1})\!)$. I don't know if there are drastically different examples, e.g., cocompact embeddings of $\mathbf{F}_p[x,y]$ into locally compact rings (other than trivial ones, e.g., taking the direct product with a compact ring).